# Applying Polybius cypher

Tags: cryptography

I need to define a function that can apply the Polybius cypher encoding technique.

I did some very basic case with if statement, however, if the input is random with A and B I have no idea how to do it (for example the input is AABA, etc).

[image]

Comment: Please include your code as text, not images. Also, explain what a Polybius cipher is, or include a link to a description.

Answer (score 3):

```
alphabet = Partition[DeleteCases[Alphabet[], "j"], 5];
lookup = AssociationThread[Flatten[alphabet] -> Tuples[Range[5], 2]];
encode[string_] := 
  Lookup[lookup, Characters[StringReplace[ToLowerCase[string], "j" -> "i"]]];
decode[code_] := StringJoin[Extract[alphabet, code]];
```

Let's try it:

```
word = RandomWord[]
code = encode[word]
decode[code]
```

> "triglyceride"
>
> {{4, 4}, {4, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {5, 4}, 
>        {1, 3}, {1, 5}, {4, 2}, {2, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}}
>
> "triglyceride"`